# How to modify the style of asp.net page that use asp:Content?

Tags: asp.net, css

I have asp.net page like this:

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent"></asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">

     ...

</asp:Content>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    BodyContent.Style["background-color"] = "Red";  // #1 This code doesn't work
}
```

I want to modify the background color of the page. I put the code above (#1) and it doesn't work.

So, how to modify the background color of the page?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
   <asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
         <div runat="server" ID="divMain">

</div>

    </asp:Content>
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {

divMain.Style.Add("background-color", "red");
}
```

**OR YOU CAN DO IT IN THIS WAY**

```
       Page.Header.Controls.Add(
    new LiteralControl(
        @"<style type='text/css'>
                .myClass
                {
                    background-color: red;

                }
                </style>
            "
        )
);
```

Comment: The background color changed only for the divMain, but not the entire page (<body>).

Comment: Page.Header.Controls.Add(
    new LiteralControl(
        @"<style type='text/css'>
                body
                {
                    background-color: red;

                }
                </style>
            "
        )
);

Comment: @ Ashfaq Shaikh: oops, yes the second method works. Is there other alternative? Thx

Comment: Actually, I set the background colour based on the value saved in cookie. So your code will be like this:            Page.Header.Controls.Add(
                new LiteralControl(
                    @"<style type='text/css'>body { background-color: " + Request.Cookies["BackgroundColor"].Value + "; }</style>"
                )
            );

Comment: you can make body tab as runat server and give it class. it will works fine.

Comment: try this one
((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ibody")).Attributes.Add("class", "myClass");

Comment: make body as <body runat="server" id="ibody">.

Comment: did you mean that I have to renounce <asp:Content> and use <body> instead?

Comment: the alternative way needs to set ID to the <body> tag, right? The problem is I don't know how to set ID to the <body> since the <body> is generated by <asp:Content>.

Comment: make it like this you can find it from master page if page inherit master page else you can have the body tag in aspx page. every .Net or HTML must have the BODY tag.
<body runat="server" id="ibody">

Comment: @ Ashfaq: I must admit that I'm still new to asp.net. I don't know what you mean by master/content page. I have updated the first post to give complete default.aspx code.

Comment: ok, I got it now. I open Site.master file. I added runat="server" and id="ibody" to <body> tag. Then I added this to Page_load:  ((System.Web.UI.HtmlControls.HtmlGenericControl)this.Page.Master.FindControl("ib‌​ody")).Style.Add("background-color", "Red");. Well done, ashfaq :)

Answer (score 5):

You can't style `Content` controls, as they don't render as any HTML element. They are just used to separate the content between files.

You can put a `style` element in the header:

```
<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
<style type="text/css">
body { background-color: red; }
</style>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: Yes, it works but I'm looking for the codebehind solution to set the background-color.

Answer (score 3):

Wrap a `DIV` around your contentplaceholder in your masterpage, and use `CSS` to style the DIV.

This will result in

```
<div class="mydiv">
<asp:ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent"> 
     ... 
</asp:Content>
</div>
```

Comment: When I try this, I receive error: Parser Error Message: Only Content controls are allowed directly in a content page that contains Content controls.